# SSIS Package will a disabled task remain disabled if deployed to SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Is a disabled task still going to run if the package is deployed to an SSIS server and executed? Or is this only a debug/design time feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No if the task is disabled inside of a SSIS package that task will not run when the package is executed on the server.